# Kendo UI Grid multi select slow and unresponsive

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI Grid which allows for multiply row selection using check boxes located on each row.

As I select each item, there is a delay before the row is highlighted.
The selection becomes progressively slow and eventually unresponsive.

I suspect the adding/removal of the classes in the function "updateNameList" is the culprit, but do not know of another way of achieving this.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyItems>() 
          .Name("MyItems")
    .DataSource(
        datasource => datasource
            .Ajax()
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetMyItems", "ItemMgr", new { id = new Guid("E1CB204D-74CD-4995-A14F-F5A6FFFCB2E7"), accountid = ViewBag.AccountId }))
            .Model(m => m.Id(mx => mx.ItemId))
        )
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' class='name-select-chk' data-target='#= Name #' />").HeaderTemplate("").Width(20);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Width(60).Title("Name");
        columns.Bound(c => c.Status).Width(60).Title("Status");                           
    .Filterable()
    .Sortable()
    .Selectable(select => select.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
    .Events(
        e=>e.Change("selection_change")
    )
   )



    function selection_change(arg) {

        var selectedItem = this.dataItem(this.select());

        if ($.inArray(selectedItem.Name, selectedNames) >= 0) {
            selectedNames.splice(selectedNames.indexOf(selectedItem.Name), 1);
        } else {
            selectedNames[selectedNames.length] = selectedItem.Name;
        }

        updateNameList(arg);
    }

    function updateNameList(e) {

        var Names = "";
        for (i = 0; i < selectedNames.length; i++) {
            Names += selectedNames[i];
            if (i < selectedNames.length-1) {
                Names += ", ";
            }
        }

        $("#MyItems tr").each(function (index) {
            $(this).removeClass("k-state-selected");
            $(this).find("input").prop('checked', false);
            for (i = 0; i < selectedNames.length; i++) {
                if ($(':nth-child(2)', this)[0].innerHTML == selectedNames[i]) {
                    $(this).addClass("k-state-selected");
                    $(this).find("input").prop('checked', true);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: were you able to get this sorted? I am facing same issue

Comment: @hellowahab It was such a long time ago, I cannot honestly say I cannot remember what we ended up doing, sorry :( I have a vague memory that my manager changed the requirements because we could not get any support to fix the issue. So the requirement was only single records could be selected. At the time this change was acceptable to the business. I also had a limited knowledge of kendo-ui and was using support forum for help.